# SPARQL to find count of grandchildren

Tags: sparql, schema.org

I am using the [schema.org](http://schema.org) ontology. I want to return the subclasses of `<http://schema.org/Event>` with the number of children for each returned subclass. My query is currently returning one subclass.

```
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
SELECT ?uri (count(?children) as ?childrenCount) WHERE 
{
  ?uri rdfs:subClassOf <http://schema.org/Event>.
  ?children rdfs:subClassOf ?uri
} 
GROUP BY ?uri
```

I want every subclass of `<http://schema.org/Event>` with the number of children it has.

Comment: What results _are_ you getting from that query?  I get the one class `UserInteraction` and a count of `9`.  I can see (and have explained in my answer) why you're not seeing more classes, but I don't see what's incorrect about this one count.  What value were you expecting?  It's hard to fix something if we don't know whether you'd consider the results we get are correct or incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake I miscounted the grandchildren, will edit question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention what “the incorrect count of its children“ is.  When I run your query on the [schema.org OWL document](http://schema.org/docs/schemaorg.owl), I get these results:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| uri                                 | childrenCount |
=======================================================
| <http://schema.org/UserInteraction> | 9             |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I think that this count is correct.  If you expected a different count, please update the question to state *what* count you expected, and why.  According to the [schema.org Full Hierarchy](http://schema.org/docs/full.html) page shows this hierarchy, under which the only grandchildren classes of `Event` are children of `UserInteraction`, and there are nine of them.

[image: type hierarchy for Event from schema.org]

At any rate, the reason you're not seeing more results in this list is that the query now only finds children that actually *have* their own children, and this restricts your results significantly.  You can select the grandchildren of `Event` inside of an `optional` pattern if you want to select the children of `Event` that themselves have no children.  To illustrate:

```
prefix schema:  <http://schema.org/>
prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select * where {
  ?child rdfs:subClassOf schema:Event .
  optional { 
    ?grandchild rdfs:subClassOf ?child
  }
}
```

produces:

```
$ arq --data schemaorg.owl --query query.sparql
--------------------------------------------------
| child                  | grandchild            |
==================================================
| schema:FoodEvent       |                       |
| schema:Festival        |                       |
| schema:SportsEvent     |                       |
| schema:SaleEvent       |                       |
| schema:EducationEvent  |                       |
| schema:ChildrensEvent  |                       |
| schema:DanceEvent      |                       |
| schema:BusinessEvent   |                       |
| schema:TheaterEvent    |                       |
| schema:SocialEvent     |                       |
| schema:VisualArtsEvent |                       |
| schema:MusicEvent      |                       |
| schema:ComedyEvent     |                       |
| schema:LiteraryEvent   |                       |
| schema:UserInteraction | schema:UserCheckins   |
| schema:UserInteraction | schema:UserTweets     |
| schema:UserInteraction | schema:UserLikes      |
| schema:UserInteraction | schema:UserPlays      |
| schema:UserInteraction | schema:UserDownloads  |
| schema:UserInteraction | schema:UserPlusOnes   |
| schema:UserInteraction | schema:UserComments   |
| schema:UserInteraction | schema:UserBlocks     |
| schema:UserInteraction | schema:UserPageVisits |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Most subclasses of `Event` don't have any subclasses;  only `UserInteraction` does.  That said, now that we see how to find these classes, even if they don't have subclasses, the counting should fall into place with a query very much like your original:

```
prefix schema:  <http://schema.org/>
prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?child (count(?grandchild) as ?nGrandchildren) where {
  ?child rdfs:subClassOf schema:Event .
  optional { 
    ?grandchild rdfs:subClassOf ?child
  }
}
group by ?child
```

The results, of course, show a count of zero for most of the classes, and nine for `UserInteraction`.

```
$ arq --data schemaorg.owl --query query.sparql
-------------------------------------------
| child                  | nGrandchildren |
===========================================
| schema:ComedyEvent     | 0              |
| schema:ChildrensEvent  | 0              |
| schema:SportsEvent     | 0              |
| schema:FoodEvent       | 0              |
| schema:BusinessEvent   | 0              |
| schema:Festival        | 0              |
| schema:EducationEvent  | 0              |
| schema:LiteraryEvent   | 0              |
| schema:SaleEvent       | 0              |
| schema:TheaterEvent    | 0              |
| schema:SocialEvent     | 0              |
| schema:UserInteraction | 9              |
| schema:MusicEvent      | 0              |
| schema:DanceEvent      | 0              |
| schema:VisualArtsEvent | 0              |
-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Great answer thanks! that is what I wanted, to retrieve the grandchildren with their count even if the count is `0`.