# SPARQL group by and order by: not ordered

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki

I follow up on [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47369041/how-to-get-grand-total-in-a-sparql-group-by-query) where the schema.org database is used to find the number of children of a class - as a simpler database than my application. I want to get the names of the children concatenated in alphabetic order. The query:

```
prefix schema:  <http://schema.org/>
prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select    ?child  (group_concat (?string) as ?strings) 
where {
  ?child  rdfs:subClassOf schema:Event .
     ?grandchild rdfs:subClassOf ?child .
  bind (strafter(str(?grandchild), "http://schema.org/") as ?string)
}   group by ?child  order by asc(?string)
limit 20
```

gives

```
schema:PublicationEvent   "OnDemandEvent BroadcastEvent"
schema:UserInteraction    "UserPageVisits UserComments UserPlays UserBlocks UserDownloads UserPlusOnes UserLikes UserCheckins UserTweets"
```

Which is not alphabetically ordered. If I replace the sort order to `desc` the result is exactly the same. I seem not to understand how `group by`, `order by` and possibly `bind` interact.

Answer (score 4):

An additional `select` subquery is required to push the order inside the groups:

```
prefix schema:  <http://schema.org/>
prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select    ?child  (group_concat (?string) as ?strings) 

where {
    select * 
    {
     ?child  rdfs:subClassOf schema:Event .
     ?grandchild rdfs:subClassOf ?child .
     bind (strafter(str(?grandchild), "http://schema.org/") as ?string)
    } order by asc(?string)
}   group by ?child  
limit 20
```

Comment: Stanislav Kralin is right. There is no guarantee that the order will be kept because `group_concat` works on multisets.

Comment: I use jena-fuseki 3.4; does in your example the order not change when you replace `asc` by `desc`?

Comment: in order to get it to work as the asker wants, the selects have to be flipped.  `group by` must be the inner one and then `order by`. `group by` ignores the previous ordering

Answer (score 2):

[*18.5.1.7 GroupConcat*](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#defn_aggGroupConcat):

> The order of the strings is not specified.

---

[From the horse's mouth](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-sparql-dev/2011AprJun/0006.html):

> On 2011-04-22, at 19:01, Steve Harris wrote:
>
> > On 2011-04-22, at 06:18, Jeen Broekstra wrote:
> >
> > > However, looking at the SPARQL 1.1 query spec, I think this is not a guaranteed result: as far as I can tell the solution modifier `ORDER BY` should be applied to the solution sequence *after* grouping and aggregation, so it can not influence the order of the input for the `GROUP_CONCAT`.
> >
> > That's correct.

Comment: The order of the strings in `group_concat` is not specified but taken from the sequence of the clauses and thus it should be defined by the `order by` clause. I found later, that an additional `select` subquery is required.

Comment: @user855443 That is not true. Stanislav Kralin is totally right. The input of `group_concat` is a multiset, thus, order will be lost. Depending on the triple store it might be retained, but according to the W3C specs there is no guarantee for it.

Comment: @StanislavKralin So seems we will have to wait till SPARQL 1.2?